# Retrieving sets in Redis and insert it into an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, socket.io

I would like to know if this is the code for retrieving sets and inserting it into an array in redis.

```
var get = client.smembers('users');
console.log(get);
```

The `users` set contains user1, user2, user2, am i able to insert this into an array `users[]` using:

```
var get = client.smembers('users');
users.push(get);
console.log(get);
```

Is there any other way in retrieving a sets? thanks guys.

Comment: no, because it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code will work.

```
var users = [];      

client.smembers('users',function(err,data){

                // data is JavaScript Array Object

                console.log(data); 

                //if you are trying to make multi dimension array
                // use users.push(data)

                users = users.concat(data); 
            });
```